# Error delete remote branch

Tags: git

Why when deleting remote branhc, I got an error like this?

```
fajar@FAJAR-PC /e/project minggu ini/ProjectTesis (master)
$ git push origin : perbaikan_1
Username for 'https://github.com': gunungloli666
Password for 'https://gunungloli666@github.com':
error: src refspec perbaikan_1 does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/gunungloli666/proj_tes.gi
t'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you do an initial commit in your local branch before trying to push?

Try this:

```
git commit -m "First commit"
```

and then push to the remote -

```
git push origin perbaikan_1
```